# How to keep transparent background in GraphicsMagick .ai to .png conversion?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

I'm using a **GraphicsMagick** package for image processing

When converting Illustrator (.ai) files to .png files, I end up losing transparency so the background ends up white.

I don't have this problem when using the same options and converting with **ImageMagick**, but I need a solution to make it work with **GraphicsMagick** specifically.

Comment: How about providing a link to an `.ai` file and the commands you are using with ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have much experience with **GraphicsMagick**, but I would assume that the behavior of **[`-background`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-background)** is the same as **ImageMagick**'s:

```
gm convert -background transparent source.ai out.png
```

*Note: This works by defining the background **before** reading the vector graphic*